# I am not able to increase my quota request on GCP even after upgrading my account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gpu, quota, google-dl-platform

I have been trying to setup a Deep Learning VM but I am not able to request for an increase in quota even after upgrading my account. I have found various answers on the internet detailing the steps but I can't seem to relate with them. My quotas page looks so much different than the others on the internet. I can't see any column for metrics and all etc. I am attaching a screenshot of my quota page with this query. [After pressing the edit quotas option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6Ivw.jpg) and [Before pressing the edit quotas option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTivB.jpg)There are two screeshots: one before pressing the edit quotas option and one after it.

I couldn't seem to find a solution as the whole layout of the webpage is different. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

it's not a problem of account type but an issue in your location. Have a look to that [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones) to see what is available in your region.

You can see that M1 VM or NVidia GPUs aren't available, it's not a quota issue, it a service availability issue.

Comment: i did take a look at it but it i still don't get why my page's interface is different than the others. other people on the internet have a completely different page layout and they get various options (like metrics etc) which i am not getting. also, acc to the documentation, it is showing that gpus are available in asia-southeast-1 . pardon me if  i am sounding stupid but i am using cloud for the first time and am a bit confused.

Comment: No, I have the same thing: a difference between my personal account, and my corporate account. In addition, the level of quotas aren't the same.